# Problem with Persian_CI_AI collation And 'ك' character

Tags: collation

I installed sql server 2008 enterprise and created a sample database whit Persian_CI_AI Collation. then from a visual studio 2010 windows application i insert the word "اسكندر" whith two type of 'ك'(arabic & Persian) but in the search time result show me just one 'اسكندر' . Please Help me

Comment: Both letters are almost the same in Persian. You'd better have chosen Persian_CS_AS (Case sensitive and accent sensitive) as the two letters seem to only differ in accent. Then it should return distinct results for your search.

Answer (score 2):

you can this procedure in vb.net for your problem

```
''' <summary>
''' این روال در برطرف کردن مشکل جستجوی حروف عربی کاربرد دارد
''' مقدار خروجی حرف ی فارسی را با یاء عربی   جایگزین میکند
''' </summary>
''' <param name="strInputValue"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function Resolve_Arabic_Font_2(ByVal strInputValue As String) As String
    Dim strOutPut As String = ""
    If strInputValue.Trim <> "" Then
        strOutPut = Replace(strInputValue, "ی", Chr(237))
    Else
        strOutPut = strInputValue
    End If
    '---------------
    Return strOutPut
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the text and then change `ك` with `ک`
also change search text with this method.