# when i replace 'ت' sql change all 'ت' and 'ة', how can i fix it?

Tags: sql, replace, char, arabic

when i replace 'ت' sql change all 'ت' and 'ة'

```
 declare @name as nvarchar(max); 
set @name  = N'ةاتی تو را است ت'; 
declare @char1 as nvarchar; 
set @char1 = N'ت'; 
declare @char2 as nvarchar; 
set @char2 = N'ب'; 
select replace(@name, @char1 ,@char2);
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Are you saying you want to change both, but it doesn't work, or that replacing one replaces the other as well and you don't want that?

Comment: What collation is the database using? And if different what is the server's default?

Comment: It seems that the initial character of @name on the right hand side has been replaced, and the intention seems to be that is should not have been replaced.  Just run the above in SSMS to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @name as nvarchar(max); 
set @name  = N'ةاتی تو را است ت'; 
declare @char1 as nvarchar; 
set @char1 = N'ت'; 
declare @char2 as nvarchar; 
set @char2 = N'ب'; 
select replace(@name Collate Persian_100_CI_AI, @char1 ,@char2);
```

to see all available collations, you may want to change CaseSensitive/Insensitive and/or Accent...

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations() FH WHERE name LIKE '%Persian%'
```

It also might be a good idea to google for other questions and results, see  [Problem with Persian_CI_AI collation And 'ك' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649421/problem-with-persian-ci-ai-collation-and-%D9%83-character)